# Get link from custom property value in umbraco 7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, hyperlink, umbraco, carousel

Hi I am using bootstrap carousel in Umbraco 7. I have a custom media type which has a property called link the type is link picker.  I want to display the link, but the code I'm using at the moment gives me a 404 error because it puts the json within the link.  Can anyone show me the correct way to retrieve the link.

```
@if(@imageItem.GetPropertyValue("linkPicker")!=null){<a href="@imageItem.GetPropertyValue("linkPicker")" style="color:#000;border-radius: 4px; padding:5px;background: rgb(255, 191, 0);float:left;">Find out more</a>}
```

Thanks in advance
Natasha

Comment: Do you know what datatype the linkpicker is? Is is the default related links or a linkpicker from a plugin?

Comment: Hi Peter it's a linkpicker from a plug in

Comment: Which one? Some plugins have helpers, with other you will have to read the json.

Comment: Hi @PeterGeerts  it's https://github.com/Gibe/Umbraco-Link-Picker. I have no idea if it has helpers but I think my code is reading the json,

Answer (score 0):

The question is about the link-picker plugin for umbraco found here:  https://github.com/Gibe/Umbraco-Link-Picker

Create a model so you can use the so you can use the link-picker strongly typed. (using Newtonsoft.Json or Newtonsoft.Json.Linq I think)

```
  public class LinkPickerModel
{
    public LinkPickerModel(string json)
    {
        JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

        Id = (int)jToken["id"];
        Name = (string)jToken["name"];
        Url = (string)jToken["url"];
        Target = (string)jToken["target"];
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
}
```

Then declare the button

```
LinkPickerModel linkPicker = new LinkPickerModel(imageItem.GetPropertyValue<string>("linkPicker"));
```

Then you can simply access the property's like this:

```
@linkPicker.Id @linkPicker.Name @linkPicker.Url @linkPicker.Target
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain as if explaining to a dummy.  I'm new to MVC and Umbraco 7.  Where do I put the model script?  Also the when I declare the button - that goes in the partial view right? Thanks again for all your help

Comment: The easiest way is to but it in the view like this:
@functions {


}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help Peter I ended up putting this code in.  it might be useful if anyone else has the same issue:

```
string jsonStr = @imageItem.GetPropertyValue("linkPicker").ToString();
                            var jsonObj = (JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
                              var link = Umbraco.TypedContent(Convert.ToInt16(@jsonObj["id"].ToString()));
                              <a href="@link.Url" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bold;">Click here to find out more</a
```

>